# output = grep.communicate()[0] returns a null when getting the battery usage details

Tags: macos, python-2.7

I am using a mac. I am writing code to get the batterylevel and batterystatus of the mac using python2.7. Below is the code I have written but I checked printing the output variable but it's empty.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import subprocess

import psutil


def getBatteryLevel():

    BATTERY_CMD = ["/usr/sbin/ioreg", "-l"]
    GREP_CMD = ["/usr/bin/egrep", "Capacity|ExternalChargeCapable"]

    process = subprocess.Popen(BATTERY_CMD, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    grep = subprocess.Popen(GREP_CMD, stdin=process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    grep.wait()
    output = grep.communicate()[0]
    batteryStatus = output.split("\n")

    maxCapacity = float(batteryStatus[1].split("=")[1].lstrip())
    curCapacity = float(batteryStatus[2].split("=")[1].lstrip())
    remaining = 100 * (curCapacity / maxCapacity)

    print "BATTERY LEVEL : "
    print remaining

getBatteryLevel()
```

I think the grep does not give output because I am using a mac mini. I tested with macbook pro and the code worked fine there

Comment: you could check the return code of `grep.wait()` to see if it's 0 or 1. `grep` probably did not find the pattern in your output. And my advice: perform the `grep` natively in python: you'll have only one subprocess and debug will be easier.

Comment: I checked with the code and grep.wait() returns 1

Comment: not surprising: pattern was not found albeit not printed: try to replace `grep = subprocess.Popen(...` by `print(process.stdout.read())` to get the output of your first command. Post that in an [edit] of your question.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I tried printing the process with print(process.stdout.read()) it gives an output with large text. I think the grep does not give output because I am using a mac mini.

Comment: I tested with macbook pro. The code works fine. :-)

Comment: So you need a rewrite without grep. I will try that

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid running sub-processes from python when you can avoid it.

The first command cannot hardly be avoided, but python is more than able to "emulate" `grep`. The less sub-processes you run the more your script is portable.

My proposal uses `check_output` for the `ioreg` call (which makes it simpler), then it splits the output using `splitlines` and filters the "interesting" lines when they match the regular expression.

```
import re

def getBatteryLevel():
    BATTERY_CMD = ["/usr/sbin/ioreg", "-l"]
    the_regex = re.compile("Capacity|ExternalChargeCapable")

    output = subprocess.check_output(BATTERY_CMD)        
    batteryStatus = [l for l in output.splitlines() if the_regex.search(l)]
```

no need for `grep` and you'll avoid it's quirks/specificities across various systems.